# scala.collection.JavaConversions$SeqWrapper cannot be cast to java.util.Set

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data

I have this cypher query:

```
start s1=node:__types__(className="xxx.domain.Soc") 
match (s1)-[:SIMILAR*]-(s2) 
with s1, count(s2) as number, collect(s2) as liste 
RETURN s1, liste 
order by number desc
```

Using spring data, I want to cast the result to an object which has 2 fields :

```
class Bean{
    private Soc soc;
    private Set<String>;
    //getters and setters
}
```

I was able to convert the node s1 to Soc but I'm getting this error when I cast the collect(s2) to Set :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.JavaConversions$SeqWrapper cannot be cast to java.util.Set
```

I'm not sure how to convert it?

Comment: Which versions are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which versions are you using?

I think this issue will be addressed in SDN 3.0.RC1 which is due today or tomorrow.

You can also try to use `Iterable<String>` as a workaround.

Comment: Works perfect with Iterable Thanks!